# Good alternative to "return" in Scala

Tags: scala, return

eg:

```
def validate(input) = {
  if (conditionA(input)) {
    return A
  }
  if (conditionB(input)) {
    return B
  }
  if (conditionC(input)) {
    return C
  }

  continueProcess(input)
}
```

Obviously there's no `return` in scala, so what's a good alternative to the above?

Comment: You **can** use `return` in Scala, it's just not recommended and not considered idiomatic.

Comment: You can change the function execution flow. Remember that in Scala `if` returns value so you can assign it to variable or make it a function result. `if (conditionA(input)) A else if (conditionB(input)) B else if (conditionC(input)) C else continueProcess(input)`. But this might not work if conditions are not mutually exclusive, so depends on logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always an issue of how much indentation you're willing to tolerate in order to avoid multiple exit points.

```
def validate(input) = {
  if      (conditionA(input)) A
  else if (conditionB(input)) B
  else if (conditionC(input)) C
  else {
    continueProcess(input)
  }
}
```

As a general rule, because FP encourages "pure" functions (no side-effects and always the same output for a given input), a single exit point is desirable.

Comment: What's wrong with indentation here? I don't see any problems.

Comment: @VictorMoroz, I was speaking generally, but in this example I indented `continueProcess()` one level more than the OP had it. If that one line of code actually represented a complex block containing more indentation then indenting it one more level might start to appear excessive.

Answer (score 1):

`return` is usable in Scala, but it's not idiomatic. Instead use one of the following alternatives:

1. just use a match:

   ```
   def validate(input) = {
     val result = input match {
       case x if conditionA(x) => A
       case x if conditionB(x) => B
       case x if conditionC(x) => C
     }
     continueProcess(input)
     result
   }
   ```
2. Also, Scala tries to make everything an expression, so `if` is an expression, too. You can also write:

   ```
   def validate(input) = {
     val result = if (conditionA(x)) 
       A
     else if (conditionB(x))
       B
     else if (conditionC(x))
       C
     else
       ???

     continueProcess(input)
     result
   }
   ```

Comment: in the first example, would `continueProcess` always be called? where do you use `result` ?

Comment: I added the `result` there, too. In general, in Scala the value of the last expression in a function is the value, that's returned. And yes, in both examples, `continueProcess` would always be called when when no exception is thrown. The `???` as well as a match error in the first example would throw an exception

Comment: @Fabian you should add it to the `else` instead of `???`, not after the `if`. 
And get rid of the `val result` thing. And in the first example, it should be `case _ continueProcess(input)` (also no `result`)

Comment: `if` is very much *not* a statement in Scala. Very few things are statements in Scala. Almost everything is an expression.

Answer (score 1):

use a match

```
def validate(input) = (conditionA(input), conditionB(input), conditionC(input)) match {
  case (true, _, _) => A
  case (false, true, _) => B
  case (false, false, true) => C
  case (false, false, false) => continueProcess(input)
}
```

Comment: All 3 computations are done no matter what, instead of doing them sequentially and short-circuiting if true. Also, what if you have 5 conditions?